# How to run Python script from QT creator and print output to GUI

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QProcess p;

// get values from ini file
settings->setValue("EMail", ui->lineEditEMail->text());
settings->setValue("Password", ui->lineEditPassword->text());

settings->setValue("Chronological", ui->checkBox->isChecked());
settings->setValue("Current_info", ui->checkBox_2->isChecked());
settings->endGroup();

settings->sync();

// launch python code for login
QString  program( "C:/projects/build-test3-Desktop_Qt_6_4_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/venv/Scripts/python.exe");
QStringList  args = QStringList() << "index.py";
QProcess::execute( program, args );

}
```

I have this function that is executed after a button is clicked and I need to print the output of "index.py" in to my app. What widget should I use and how? From what I read QTextBrowser should do the trick but I'm not sure how to use it. [image: GUI]

This is how my GUI looks like. I'd like to use to output my results somewhere in button right. I didn't add the widget yet, because I'm not sure QTextBrowser is the one I need

Comment: QTextEdit is the control you need.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Botje, could you walk me through on how to make my Python output get printed to QTextEdit?

Comment: There are tons of duplicates for "[qt] read process output".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget you could use for this purpose is [`QTextEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html) (you can set it to be read-only from the graphical user interface).

But if you want to get the output of the execution, you will need a proper instance of `QProcess` and call the [`QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html) member function to get the standard output.

You may also be interested by `QProcess::readAllStandardError()` to get the errors in case of failure.

---

**Edit (simple/basic example):**

```
QProcess p;
p.start("path/to/python.exe", QStringList("script.py"));

p.waitForFinished();
QByteArray p_stdout = p.readAllStandardOutput();
QByteArray p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();

// Do whatever you want with the results (check if they are not empty, print them, fill your QTextEdit contents, etc...)
```

***Note:*** If you don't want to be blocking with `QProcess::waitForFinished()`, you can use a signal/slots connection on `QProcess::finished()` signal.

Comment: What is the proper instance of QProcess? Why is mine bad?

Comment: Yours is not bad, you have none. You are calling a `static` function of `QProcess` class. But for more advanced usage (like getting the output for example), you will need an actual instance of `QProcess`, not only `static` calls. An instance on which you could use non-static member functions like `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` for example :)

Comment: Do you have an example by any chance?

Comment: Ouch, if you don't know how to create an instance of a class, I would advise you to start by getting a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and take the time to learn C++ properly because it really is the basics of the basics. By the way, in your function, you already have an (unused) instance of `QProcess` that you called `p`.

Comment: @Modestas I have given a small example about how to get the output with `QProcess`, I leave the rest to you. StackOverflow is not a free coding service :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'll try to pull it off. Thank you for your comments and assistance